# Hover bug when there are other elements on div

Tags: hover

I have this site https://pastebin.com/LasNaFxJ with this .css https://pastebin.com/JasKwtGR . When I put my mouse over the div 'glider' it works and it goes down, but if I have for example a paragraph in this div when I hover the paragraph it shakes the div a couple of times. If it's normal text it doesn't, but I want to know what can I do to stop this shaking. I tried `<p id="glider">..</p>` but doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Pastebin is extremely unhelpful here. Can you please make some example demonstration using Javascript/HTML/CSS snipped editor on this site, so we can see what the problem is immediately?

Comment: A link to the editor pls?

Comment: If you click "edit question", one of the buttons on top of the text area opens up jsfiddle-like editor.